# Run background task on ios - react native 0.60

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native, background-task

I would like to execute a piece of code just after my application goes into the background.

From what I read this is possible with the use of the library react-native-fetch-background (At the beginning I wanted to do it for iOS) but this feature is limited.

I will have to wait for at least 15 since the app enters background to execute the task, but I care for this code to be executed just after my app goes into background.

Is there any way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about react-native native implementation but using your own code in file *AppDelegate.m* callback method

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {
      //notify react native about app goes into the background
}
```